# Nullify an attribute when another attribute has been nullified

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a model with three foreign keys that point to the same table.  When one of the foreign keys is set to `NULL`, I also want to nullify the other two foreign keys.

```
primary_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(table.id))
secondary_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(table.id))
tertiary_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey(table.id))
```

My initial thought was to setup an event listening for `set` but that will recurse indefinitely.

```
@event.listens_for(Model.primary_id, 'set')
@event.listens_for(Model.secondary_id, 'set')
@event.listens_for(Model.tertiary_id, 'set')
def example(target, value, old, initiator):
    target.primary_id = None
    target.secondary_id = None
    target.tertiary_id = None
```

Is there some way for me to stop the events propagation if I know the source is the `example` function provided above?

Comment: Can't you have three different functions, each attached to a different `set` event?

Comment: @univerio Unfortunately, it raises the same issue.  They will still recurse indefinitely as the events bounce between the three functions.

Comment: Hm. Maybe set a flag on the instance and check the flag before you set anything?

Comment: @univerio Ayyyyy that did the trick.  Thanks bud!